# How to display data on web by using .tpl with data from nested json with template is .tpl

Tags: json, go, templates, nested, beego

I want to display data using beego and golang. But I have a problem because I get is nested json data and I can't find a way to solve it, can you help me cause i'm new in beego and golang.

here's the nested json i got

```
[{
  "AppId":1233,
  "AppStatus":"approved",
  "AppStatusVerification":"retur",
  "AppFullname":"Dadang Subur",
  "UpdatedAt":"2022-03-31T11:54:07.283Z",
  "CreatedAt":"2021-03-23T06:20:07.877Z",
  "History":[
     {
        "Id":1233,
        "Name":"approved",
        "Time":"2022-03-28T17:31:24.55Z",
        "ActorId":1232,
        "ActorName":""
     },
     {
        "Id":1233,
        "Name":"approved",
        "Time":"2022-03-28T16:33:29.033Z",
        "ActorId":1232,
        "ActorName":""
     }}]
```

And code .tpl i used

```
<tbody>
    {{range $record := .records}}
       <tr>
         <td>{{$record.AppId}}</td>
         <td>{{$record.AppFullname}}</td>
         <td>{{$record.AppStatus}}</td>
         <td>{{$record.CreatedAt}}</td>
         <td>{{$record.UpdatedAt}}</td>
        </tr>
     {{end}}
</tbody>
```

Cause when i used `<td>{{$record.Name}}</td>` to get *"approved"*, the result is *executing "eform/listAllActivityHistoryAgent.tpl" at <$record.Name>: can't evaluate field Name in type models.HistoryData*

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

History is also an array so you need to iterate in the tpl.

Please try this;

```
<tbody>
    {{range $record := .records}}
       <tr>
         <td>{{$record.AppId}}</td>
         <td>{{$record.AppFullname}}</td>
         <td>{{$record.AppStatus}}</td>
         <td>{{$record.CreatedAt}}</td>
         <td>{{$record.UpdatedAt}}</td>
         {{range $history := $record.History}}
         <td>{{$history.Name}}</td>
         {{end}}
        </tr>
     {{end}}
</tbody>
```